# Univariate root-finding with minimum number of function evaluations

Tags: python, matlab, numerical-methods

I am looking for root-finding algorithms that use very few function evaluations (the aim is the minimum). The root-finding problem has the following characteristics:

`f(x) = 0, R -> R`

- the function (`f(.)`) evaluation is extremely costly*;
- bounding interval (`[a,b]`) is available for start (relatively good approximation, not a wild guess);
- `f(.)` is continuous;
- `f(.)` is differentiable (analytic derivative is not available);
- it is known that only a single root lies within the starting interval (`[a,b]`);
- smoothly varying `f(.)` (nothing extreme is expected from the function);
- permissive stopping criteria, e.g. `|f(x)| < 1e-2` is sufficient.

*We can safely assume that any calculation done by the algorithm is negligible compared to a single evaluation of `f(.)`. Thus saving even a single function evaluation is a significant gain.

**Given these what is(are) the most efficient algorithm(s) to find the root with the least number of function evaluations?**

Based on Matlab's [`fzero`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) and scipy's [`root-finding functions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), Brent's method seems to the popular choice, though there might be a more efficient algorithm for the specific problem described above.

References to books and review articles are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to try Brent's method you can try my translation of the original algorithm below. This is just my translation of the original C code into MATLAB. I've verified that all of the test cases for the original C code produce identical results in my translation.

In the code below `This` is a function handle, and `a` and `b` are the search bounds.

```
function x = brent(This,a,b) 

tol = 1e-2 ;
maxit = 1e+3 ;
displayIter = true ;

Fa = This(a) ;
Fb = This(b) ;
c = a ;
Fc = Fa ;

it = 0 ;
if displayIter
    fprintf(1,'Searching for a root in the interval [%g,%g] using Brent''s method...\n',a,b) ;
end
while it<maxit
    it = it + 1 ;

    prevStep = b - a ;

    if abs(Fc) < abs(Fb)
        % swap for b to be best approximation
        a = b ;
        b = c ;
        c = a ;
        Fa = Fb ;
        Fb = Fc ;
        Fc = Fa ;
    end

    tolAct =  2*eps*abs(b) + tol/2 ;

    newStep = (c-b)/2 ;

    if abs(newStep) <= tolAct || abs(Fb)<eps
        % acceptable solution found
        x = b ;
        return 
    end

    if abs(prevStep) >= tolAct && Fa == Fb
        % previous step was large enough and in the right direction, try
        % interpolation
        cb = c-b ;
        if abs(a-c)<eps
            % if only two distinct points, interpolate linearly
            t1 = Fb/Fa ;
            p = cb*t1 ;
            q = 1 - t1 ;
        else
            % three points, do quadratic inverse  interpolation
            a = Fa/Fc ;
            t1 = Fb/Fc ;
            t2 = Fb/Fa ;
            p = t2*( cb*q*(q-t1) - (b-a)*(t1-1) ) ;
            q = (q-1)*(t1-1)*(t2-1) ;
        end
        if p>0
            q = -q ;
        else
            p = -p ;
        end
        if p < ( 0.75*cb*q-abs(tolAct*q)/2 ) && p < abs(prevStep*q/2)
            newStep = p/q ;
        end
    end
    % step must be at least as large as tolerance
    if abs(newStep)<tolAct
        if newStep>0
            newStep = tolAct ;
        else
            newStep = -tolAct ;
        end
    end

    a = b ;
    Fa = Fb ;
    b = b + newStep ;
    Fb = This(b) ;
    if ( Fb > 0 && Fc > 0 ) || ( Fb < 0 && Fc < 0 )
        c = a ;
        Fc = Fa ;
    end
    if displayIter
        fprintf(1,'[%g] Gap = %g, dx = %g\n',it,abs(Fb),newStep) ;
    end
end
fprintf(1,'[%g] Gap = %g, dx = %g\n',it,abs(Fb),newStep) ;

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your code (3). I've already tested Brent's method, besides `fzero` (1) I am using [this](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/brent/zero.m)(2)  Matlab implementation as well.  A quick test using `fun = @(x) exp(-exp(-x)) - x` and `x0 = [0, 1]` with `tolx = 1e-2` shows the following function evaluation numbers: (1) 5; (2) 4; (3) 7. I am seeking for something more efficient. :)